# How to replace a value in one field by a value from another field (different column) within the same view table (SQL)?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I'd like to know if it is possible to replace a value from one field by using a value from another column and a different row.

[For Example, click this to view the table image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UZbkV.png)

I'd like the `SumRedeemed` value 400 in row 15 to be replaced by the value -1*(-395); the value -395 comes from the `EarnPointsLeft` in row 6 (both have the same CID meaning that they are the same person). Any suggestions?

Comment: Edit your question and show the result set that you want.  Also, what is "field #1" and "field #6"?  That is not apparent from your sample data.

Comment: Hi, I've reedited the question with a screenshot of the table and coding references. Are there any suggestions?

Comment: An `update` trigger that doesn't reference `inserted` and `deleted` is unusual. Which row do you suppose will supply the value for `set @CID = (select CID from FifoPtsView)`?

Answer (score 0):

You need this update statement:

```
update t
set t.sumredeemed = (-1) * (select earnpointsleft from FifoPtsView where cid = t.cid)
from FifoPtsView t
where t.cid = 5000100008 and t.earnpointsleft = 0
```

This will work if the select statement will return only 1 row.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply update your table

```
update t
set t.sumredeemed = ABS(t2.earnpointsleft )
from FifoPtsView t join FifoPtsView t2 on t.cid = t.cid and isnull(t2.earnpointsleft,0)>0
```

if you want negative values you can remove ABS ,
please give me your feedbacks